# Series of zero a.s functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a sequence of measurable functions $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$
**each of which is zero almost surely on $\Omega$.** If we define pointwisely $$f(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(\omega)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i,$$ is the bold condition enough for f to be Zero almost surely?..

Im confuse how "a.s." Works on infinite series. Any hints\help\insights is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fort each $i$ there is a set $E_i$ of measure $0$ such that $f_i(x)=0$ if $x \notin E_i$. Let $E=\cup_i E_i$. Then $E$ has measure $0$  and $f(x)=\sum f_i(x)=\sum 0=0$ for $x \notin E$. Hence $f=0$ a.e..